# Alternative to history.go(-1) for FireFox and Safari

Tags: javascript

Is there an alternative to history.go(-1) for FireFox and Safari. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue you've got with history.go(-1)? If you told us, you'd probably get more appropriate help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `history.back()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Link</a>
```

Should work though.

Because, indeed, the following does not work in Firefox:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Javascript:goback();">some Text</a>

function goback() {
   history.go(-1);
}
```

Is that what you were doing ?

Comment: Is that also true if the goBack() function would return false?